# does output from keras fit show average of loss?

Tags: keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, loss

I am using binary cross entropy, and I have 2 epochs:

```
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2
History = model.fit(padded_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs, validation_split = 0.1)
```

Now i get the following output

```
loss: 0.0771 - accuracy: 0.9763 - val_loss: 0.0575 - val_accuracy: 0.9806
```

Now what i am wondering is, whether the loss i am seeing here signifies an average of the loss for all observations, or maybe just the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only for the 2nd epoch you should get an output below saying: Accuracy x%. x is representing the accuracy of the whole 2 epochs

Comment: so is a average, or maybe a mean? also i only have 2 epochs, it surely wont have 32 epochs to get metris from?

Comment: Sorry, I read the data wrong, for a more accurate reading you need more epochs, and the data you got was an average for that epoch where are there should have been another output of what I described

Comment: ah, yes thanks a lot. 
Yes i kinda figured that 2 epochs wouldnt render any super accurate metrics, but its just kind of a exercise
but thanks a lot